# jquery post append specific $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, post

I need to send a specific $_POST in jQuery (for example $_POST['function']). How can I achieve that?

I know that if is a form I could use something like:

```
var formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('function', 'function_name');
```

And it will send in the $_POST a field with 'function' name ($_POST['function']).
Now, I need to send only a variable info (id) and the function name, but I can't achieve it.

```
id.append('function', 'function_name');
```

It doesnt as it's only a variable. The rest of my code:

```
        $.ajax({ url: '../inc/call.php',
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: id,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(output) {
...
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
id.append is not a function
```

How can I send this info?
Also I want to return from PHP an array full of data. How should I handle it and work it with jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to send over `id` field to your script. In order to do that you must append all your data to the FormData object. i.e. below your `formData.append('function', 'function_name');` line add another line like `formData.append('id', id);`

Comment: The problem is there isn't a form really. Imagine I need to send var ID as $_POST['id'] and var function as $_POST['function'], all in the same post. I can't create a formdata from no form I guess.

Comment: create an empty `FormData` then append what you want then just send it as your `POST` parameters.

Comment: `var post = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['function']); ?>`

Comment: You don't even need a form to create a `FormData` it's a class and independent from the `<form>` you have. Just create it like `new FormData()` and `append` what you need to it.